# ViewPager displays shadows on Fragments after notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-fragmentactivity

I'm making a simple flashcard app using a ViewPager, FragmentStatePagerAdapter, and some card flipping animations found on the offical Android tutorials (https://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html). I've created a shuffle button which shuffles the cards in the deck and then calls notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter to update the card views. Once called, it successfully updates the views, but it also creates a shadow/border around each card that doesn't clear until the card is touched and flipped.

When initially launched, the cards are basically have no border.
[Here is what the cards look like after I spam the shuffle button. The border darkens on every press:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7GgW.png)

Here are some snippets of the relevant parts of my code:

**MainAcivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.shuffleButton:
            pager.removeAllViews();
            pagerAdapter.shuffle();
            pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
    return true;
```

**CardPagerAdapter.java**

```
public class CardPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public static final String CARD = "CARD";
    private static final float WIDTH_SCALE = 0.95f;

    private int count;
    private Deck deck;
    private ArrayList<Card> cards;
    private boolean isShuffled;

    public CardPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Deck deck) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.deck = deck;
        this.count = deck.getSize();
        this.cards = deck.getCards();
        this.isShuffled = false;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        CardContainerFragment cardContainerFragment = new 
               CardContainerFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(CARD, cards.get(position));
        cardContainerFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return cardContainerFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object item) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Override the pageWidth in order to be able
     * to see other cards on the side of the current card.
     * @param position The position of the current card
     * @return The multiplier by which to change the width by
     */
    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return WIDTH_SCALE;
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        if (isShuffled) {
            cards = deck.getCards();
        } else {
            Collections.shuffle(cards);
        }
        isShuffled = !isShuffled;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**CardContainerFragment.java**

```
public class CardContainerFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String FLIPPED = "FLIPPED";
    private static final float DISTANCE = 8000;

    private CardFragment frontCardFragment;
    private CardFragment backCardFragment;
    private boolean cardFlipped;

    public CardContainerFragment() {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Create the card fragment view
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.card_fragment, container, false);

        this.cardFlipped = false;
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

        // Make the front and back cards
        Bundle frontBundle = (Bundle) bundle.clone();
        Bundle backBundle = (Bundle) bundle.clone() ;

        frontCardFragment = new CardFragment();
        frontBundle.putByte(FLIPPED, (byte) 0);
        frontCardFragment.setArguments(frontBundle);

        backCardFragment = new CardFragment();
        backBundle.putByte(FLIPPED, (byte) 1);
        backCardFragment.setArguments(backBundle);

        // Set the first viewed fragment to be the the front of the card
        getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, frontCardFragment)
            .commit();

        // Flip the card once touched
        rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                flipCard();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * Swaps the visible fragment with the other fragment (the other side of 
       the card)
     * Animates the transition between the change with a flip animation.
     */
    public void flipCard() {
        Fragment fragment;
        if (cardFlipped) {
            fragment = frontCardFragment;
        } else {
            fragment = backCardFragment;
        }


        getChildFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(
                    R.animator.card_flip_left_in,
                    R.animator.card_flip_left_out,
                    R.animator.card_flip_right_in,
                    R.animator.card_flip_right_out)
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();

        cardFlipped = !cardFlipped;
    }

    public static class CardFragment extends Fragment {

        private TextView cardText;
        private ImageButton starButton;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup 
                             container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Create the card fragment view and get the card object
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_view, container, 
                                         false);

            Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
            final Card card = bundle.getParcelable(CardPagerAdapter.CARD);

            boolean cardFlipped = bundle.getByte(FLIPPED) != 0;

            // Change camera perspective to not have the flip animation be 
            // distorted
            float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            view.setCameraDistance(DISTANCE * scale);

            // Set the text from the card to the fragment's textview
            cardText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardText);
            if (cardFlipped) {
                cardText.setText(card.getBackText());
            } else {
                cardText.setText(card.getFrontText());
            }

            // Make the star button and set it based on if the card is 
            // starred
            starButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.starButton);
            if (card.isStarred()) {
                starButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_star_white_48dp);
            } else {
            starButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_star_border_black_48dp);
            }
            starButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (!card.isStarred()) {

                   starButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_star_white_48dp);
                    } else {

            starButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_star_border_black_48dp);
                    }
                    card.toggleStarred();
                }
            });


            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help at all would be appreciated.

***EDIT**
As requested here is the XML

**card_fragment.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null">

</FrameLayout>
```

**card_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cardText"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="This is the card contents."
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/starButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:tint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/cardText"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cardText"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_star_border_black_48dp" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d3d3d3"
    tools:context="com.benvo.viewpager.activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/deckProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: give us your xml please

Comment: change android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  in the android.support.v7.widget.CardView  to "match_parent" and see what happens

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: sorry, where did you use `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`?

Comment: I edited the post again.

Comment: copy your viewpager from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#viewpager).